# ROS Answers SE migration: joystick ros

Tags: joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Is there a step by step tutorial for interfacing joystick to ros and controlling the motors of base. I have logitech wireless gamepad F710 joystick can i use this in ros? can anyone suggest what wifi supported low cost controller to use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30448/joystick-ros/) by [priya](https://answers.ros.org/users/2051/priya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-09-19**:
could you work with that one? because I want to buy one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please search [joystick](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?q=joystick) on ros.org and have a look at the tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jie Sky](https://answers.ros.org/users/20509/jie-sky/) on 2014-11-25**:
I have searched a lot .But i have not realize it.Do you know how to use a normal joystick to control a turtlebot based kobuki?I have some trouble with it . I refer to this website:http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_teleop/Tutorials/hydro/Joystick%20Teleop  .Thank you.